# "java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 'long org.RDKit.RDKFuncsJNI.RWMol_MolFromSmiles__SWIG_3(java.lang.String)'"

Tags: java, rdkit

I want to use RDkit in my java web project. It happens  like this "I want to use RDkit in my java web project. It happens  like this".
It is so weird.I wirte a sample java application like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
 System.loadLibrary("GraphMolWrap");//I have put the .dll file in the path
 String smiles = "CN1CCN2C(C1)C1=C(CC3=C2C=CC=C3)C=CC=C1";//my pom.xml import the jar
 RWMol m1 = RWMol.MolFromSmiles(smiles);
}
```

It runs without any bug!
But When I put its code in my springboot project.It happens like title.

Answer (score 0):

I know where's is the bug.It is about the maven package for springboot.If run with the command,it will run formally.